# Capitalization in dissertation

Tags: formatting

I am currently finishing my dissertation.
I have a Table of Contents, a List of Figures, and a List of Tables.

While I was trying to consistently (de)capitalize my headings of the chapters, figures, and tables, I realized that, by default, the List of Figures, for instance, is capitalized. 
Is this necessary, i.e., do I capitalize "List of Figures" even though the captions of the figures are not capitalized?

Thank you.

Comment: The standard answer to all such questions is that one should do whatever the relevant style manual says; this is not a matter of the general rules of English language and usage. It can, however, be said that, unless one has been asked to follow some style manual that says otherwise, the chapter headings, table captions, etc. should appear in the table of contents and similar list in the same form in which they appear in the body of the text; setting them out differently may be confusing to the reader. The defaults of the word-processing software should not control the matter.

Comment: Your advisor is likely the best authority for this; if not, your department or other faculty unit or the institution as a whole may have a preferred [style manual](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2579) which you can consutt on such matters.